# Standard error of the success rate of a collection of different binomial distributions (whose success rates need to be estimated)

Tags: binomial-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

I would like to estimate the correct percentage of tweets that are written in a particular language from a collection of followers of a given account . The goal is to compare different accounts to check which one has the highest percentage of tweets in a specific language among its followers. Since I cannot download all follower's tweets for a given account, I need to estimate the population mean out of the sample I am able to get. But I am pretty confused about the right way to do it.

Let's say I have 50 tweets from each of 1000 random followers' accounts. Therefore, there is uncertainty both in estimating $p_i$ for each follower and in estimating the global average. I consider language of each tweet of a given account as a Bernoulli distribution: success if the tweet is in the goal language, failure otherwise. For each follower i, we have a binomial distribution with a particular success rate pi, that we need to estimate from the sample of 50 tweets. But the goal is to estimate the correct percentage of tweets in a specific language for all followers of the account : the average follower.

Initially, I made the assumption of considering the array of size n = 50 *
 1000 (i.e, num_tweets_per_follower * num_followers_tracked) as a binomial sample of size n. I can easily compute the fraction of success tweets and then standard error just by using the formula

$SE = \sqrt{(\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})/N)}$

But I think this assumption is wrong. Each sample of 50 tweets per follower $i$ with different $p_i$ has an error I am not actually considering. Should I use a $\hat{p}_i$ for each follower? But then, how should I compute the global estimate ?

As you can see it is not clear to me whether the solution is very simple or actually more articulated.

Comment: I think I sorted out my confusion. I just need to estimate each separate success rate for each follower and consider them as independent random variables, then estimate the standard error of the global mean by taking the square root of the sum of the variances of each rate estimate